# Поиск окружности на изображении OpenCV + Python 3.6

Tags: python, opencv

Мне необходимо найти окружность, которая выделена на фотографии.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал программу, которая с помощью цветовых фильтров оставляет необходимую окружность(и немного остального изображения)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("123.bmp")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def nothing(*arg):
        pass

cv2.namedWindow( "result" ) 
cv2.namedWindow( "settings" ) 

cv2.createTrackbar('h1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('h2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('bloor', 'settings', 0, 10, nothing)

while True:
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV )

    bloor = cv2.getTrackbarPos('bloor', 'settings')
    h1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h1', 'settings')
    s1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s1', 'settings')
    v1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v1', 'settings')
    h2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h2', 'settings')
    s2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s2', 'settings')
    v2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v2', 'settings')

    if bloor % 2 == 0:
        bloor = bloor + 1

    h_min = np.array((h1, s1, v1), np.uint8)
    h_max = np.array((h2, s2, v2), np.uint8)


    hsv = cv2.GaussianBlur(hsv, (bloor, bloor), 2)
    thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, h_min, h_max)

    cv2.imshow('result', thresh)

    ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if ch == 27:
        break
```

Такая картина получается при настройках:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я начал пытаться найти окружность, но мои старания были четны. Я бы хотел попросить у Вас помощи, подскажите, как реализовать нахождение окружности.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На нижнем изображении окружность хорошо выделяется, так что можно применить функцию [HoughCircles](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html) (использует преобразование Хафа для обнаружения окружностей и определения их параметров).

Должно получиться две хороших окружности. Вот часть примера из ссылки на Python:

```
gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv.medianBlur(gray, 5)

rows = gray.shape[0]
circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 8,
                               param1=100, param2=30,
                               minRadius=1, maxRadius=30)


    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0, :]:
            center = (i[0], i[1])
            # circle center
            cv.circle(src, center, 1, (0, 100, 100), 3)
            # circle outline
            radius = i[2]
            cv.circle(src, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 3)
```

Comment: Благодарю, все отлично получилось, только вы забыли строку        
`rows = gray.shape[0]` В самом начале

Answer (score 1):

Начальное изображение:
[image: Начальное изображение]
Нахождение окружности на изображении обработанным фильтром:
[image: Нахождение окружности на изображении обработанным фильтром]
Выделение круга на начальном изображении:
[image: Выделение круга на начальном изображении]

Благодарю за помощь :)